# Principal component analysis with EQUAMAX rotation

Tags: r, pca, rotational-matrices

I need to do a principal component analysis (PCA) with `EQUAMAX-rotation` in `R`.

Unfortunately the function `principal()` I normally use for PCA does not offer this kind of rotation.

I could find out that it may be possible somehow with the package `GPArotation` but I could not yet figure out how to use this in the PCA.

Maybe someone can give an example on how to do an `equamax-rotation` PCA?

Or is there a function for PCA in another package that offers the use of `equamax-rotation` directly?

Answer (score 3):

The package `psych` from i guess you are using `principal()` has the rotations `varimax`, `quatimax`, `promax`, `oblimin`, `simplimax`, and `cluster` but not `equamax`  ([psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) p.232) which is a compromise between Varimax and Quartimax

excerpt from the STATA manual:  [mvrotate](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/mvrotate.pdf) p.3

> **Rotation criteria**

In the descriptions below, the matrix to be rotated is denoted as **A**, p denotes the number of rows of A, and f denotes the number of columns of **A** (factors or components). If **A** is a loading matrix from factor or pca, p is the number of variables, and f is the number of factors or components.

> 

**Criteria suitable only for orthogonal rotations**

> 

`varimax` and `vgpf` apply the orthogonal `varimax` rotation (Kaiser 1958). `varimax` maximizes the variance of the squared loadings within factors (columns of A). It is equivalent to `cf`(1/p) and to `oblimin`(1). `varimax`, the most popular rotation, is implemented with a dedicated fast algorithm and ignores all optimize options. Specify `vgpf` to switch to the general GPF algorithm used for the other criteria.

> 

`quartimax` uses the `quartimax` criterion (Harman 1976). `quartimax` maximizes the variance of
the squared loadings within the variables (rows of **A**). For orthogonal rotations, `quartimax` is equivalent to `cf`(0) and to `oblimax`.

> 

`equamax` speciﬁes the orthogonal `equamax` rotation. `equamax` maximizes a weighted sum of the
`varimax` and `quartimax` criteria, reﬂecting a concern for simple structure within variables (rows of **A**) as well as within factors (columns of **A**). `equamax` is equivalent to `oblimin(p/2)` and `cf(#)`, where # = f /(2p).

now the `cf` (Crawford-Ferguson) method is also available in [`GPArotation`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GPArotation/GPArotation.pdf)

> 

`cfT` orthogonal Crawford-Ferguson family

> 

`cfT(L, Tmat=diag(ncol(L)), kappa=0, normalize=FALSE, eps=1e-5, maxit=1000)`

> 

The argument kappa parameterizes the family for the Crawford-Ferguson method. If m is the number of factors and p is the number of indicators then kappa values having special names are 0=Quartimax, 1/p=Varimax, m/(2*p)=Equamax, (m-1)/(p+m-2)=Parsimax, 1=Factor parsimony.

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(500), ncol=10)
C <- cor(X)
eig <- eigen(C)
# PCA by hand scaled by sqrt
eig$vectors * t(matrix(rep(sqrt(eig$values), 10), ncol=10))
require(psych)
PCA0 <- principal(C, rotate='none', nfactors=10) #PCA by psych
PCA0

# as the original loadings PCA0 are scaled by their squarroot eigenvalue
apply(PCA0$loadings^2, 2, sum) # SS loadings

## PCA with Equimax rotation
# now i think the Equamax rotation can be performed by cfT with m/(2*p)
# p number of variables (10) 
# m (or f in STATA manual) number of components (10)
# gives m==p --> kappa=0.5

PCA.EQ <- cfT(PCA0$loadings, kappa=0.5)
PCA.EQ
```

I upgraded some of my `PCA` knowledge by your question, hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 2):

Walter's answer helped a great deal!
I'll add some sidenotes for what it's worth:

- R's psych::principal says under option "rotate", that more rotations are available. Under the linked "fa", there's in fact an "equamax". Sadly, the results are neither replicable with STATA nor with SPSS, at least not with the standard syntax I tried:

  ```
  # R:
  PCA.5f=principal(data, nfactors=5, rotate="equamax", use="complete.obs")
  ```
- Walter's solution replicates SPSS' equamax rotation (Kaiser-normalized by default) in the first 3 decimal places (i.e. loadings and rotating matrix fairly equivalent) using the following syntax with m=no of factors and p=no of indicators:

  ```
  # R:
  PCA.5f=principal(data, nfactors=5, rotate="none", use="complete.obs")
  PCA.5f.eq = cfT(PCA.5f$loadings, kappa=m/(2*p), normalize=TRUE) # replace kappa factor formula with your actual numbers!

  # SPSS:
  FACTOR
  /VARIABLES listofvariables
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /ANALYSIS listofvariables
  /PRINT ROTATION  
  /CRITERIA FACTORS(5) ITERATE(1000)
  /EXTRACTION PC
  /CRITERIA ITERATE(1000)
  /ROTATION EQUAMAX
  /METHOD=CORRELATION.
  ```
- STATA's equamax - Kaiser-normalized and unnormalized - is replicable at least in the first 4 decimal places with Kappa .5 irrespective of your actual number of factors and indicators which seems to contradict their manual (c.f. Walter's citation).

  ```
  # R:
  PCA.5f=principal(data, nfactors=5, rotate="none", use="complete.obs")
  PCA.5f.eq = cfT(PCA.5f$loadings, kappa=.5, normalize=TRUE)  

  # STATA:
  factor listofvars,   pcf factors(5) 
  rotate,  equamax normalize # kick the "normalize" to replicate R's "normalize=FALSE"
  mat list e(r_L)
  ```