# Replicating results of SPSS PCA with Equamax rotation in R

Tags: r, pca, spss

Having used SPSS for many years I now want to switch to R. For consistency in findings I want to replicate previous SPSS results in R. I am not a statistician and I am quite new in learning R. I encounter some difficulties when it comes to getting the same outcomes of PCA with Equamax rotation in SPSS and R. The desired output should include:

1. a “nice” rotated component matrix (no scores off-diagonal)
2. scores for each observation.

In order to recreate an example, I have done the following:

```
#Open the Chatterjee-Price Attitude Data
df <- attitude[,-1]
df <- as.data.frame(scale(df))

#Write to SPSS file
library(haven)   
write_sav(df, "Attitude scaled.sav")

#Run SPSS syntax
#* Encoding: UTF-8.
#FACTOR
#  /VARIABLES 
# complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
#  /MISSING
#  LISTWISE /ANALYSIS 
# complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
#  /PRINT ROTATION
#  /FORMAT SORT BLANK(.40)
#  /CRITERIA FACTORS(6) ITERATE(1000)
#  /EXTRACTION PC
#  /CRITERIA ITERATE(1000)
#  /ROTATION EQUAMAX
#  /SAVE REG(ALL)
# /METHOD=CORRELATION .
```

This results in the desired Rotated Component Matrix and Factor scores in SPSS.
Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images, but the diagonal reads:

```
advance 0.926
privileges 0.931
critical 0.981
complaints 0.873
learning 0.869
raises 0.819
```

And the six scores for the first observation are:

```
FAC1_1  0.55904
FAC2_1  -1.81149
FAC3_1  1.86281
FAC4_1  -0.54449
FAC5_1  -1.26223
FAC6_1 -0.09140
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300853/principal-component-analysis-with-equamax-rotation-in-r) post, I am able to already get quite similar results in R:

```
library(psych)
library(GPArotation)
PCA0 <- principal(df, rotate='none', nfactors=6) #PCA by psych
PCA.EQ <- cfT(PCA0$loadings, kappa=0.5, normalize=TRUE)
rotmatrix_cft <- PCA.EQ$loadings
rotmatrix_cft[abs(rotmatrix_cft)<0.4] <- "" #Supressing low values for clarity
rotmatrix_cft <- dfOrder(rotmatrix_cft, -(1:6)) #Sorting the diagonal
```

I can see why the ordering of the PC’s differs between SPSS and R, because SPSS sorts during the process using all scores and in R I have done it afterwards with only the diagonal (suggestions on how to change that are of course welcome).
Two things are unclear to me:

1. Why is there a negative loading for “advance” in the diagonal while it is not in SPSS?
2. How to get the individual regression scores for each observation as in SPSS, because PCA0$scores do not correspond with the FAC-scores in SPSS?